# NodeJS checking multiple db entries by looping through mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where a user checks off a list of companies in a form and then submits the form, which includes a file upload. This gets passed to the server by a string of IDs separated by ';' as a multipart/form.

On the NodeJS side, I'd like to check that all of these company IDs exist in the database, plus check some other things, and if any of these checks fails, then 1) delete the files uploaded (which, since I'm using Multer, I upload to a temp folder while checking some of these things; 2) return an error.

Something along these lines:

```
router.post("/", [ ... some express validator stuff ... ], upload.array('files'),
(req, res, err) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
        errors.push({ message: "FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR" });
    }
        
    // Date error
    var date = new Date(req.body.date);
    const dateError = !date.getTime();
    if (dateError) {
        errors.push({ message: "INVALID_DATE" });
    }

    // Check whether companies exist
    var companies = req.body.companies.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
        companySchema.findById( companies[i], function (err, company) {
            if (err || !company) {
                errors.push({ message: "COMPANY_NOT_EXIST_ERROR"});
            }
        } );
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(temp_folder + req.files[i].filename);
            } catch(err) {
                errors.push({ message: "DELETE_FILE_ERROR"});
            }
        }

        return res.status(422).json({
            message: errors.message
        })
    }
    else { console.log("success!")};

});
```

Obviously the snippet:                 `if (err || !company) { errors.push({ message: "COMPANY_NOT_EXIST_ERROR"}); }` causes a couple issues, including: I believe it's async so the rest of the code executes before these queries are done; the scope of the query can't see my 'errors' variable, I don't know how to handle the error/result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `findById` in a loop it's better to use [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) along with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) operator:

```
companySchema.find({ _id: { $in: companies } }, { _id: 1 }, function (err, queryResult) {
    for(let company of companies){
        if(!queryResult.find(x => x._id === company )){
            errors.push({ message: "COMPANY_NOT_EXIST_ERROR"});
        }
    }
});
```

Such query returns only an array of `_id` fields (which is all you need) and you can compare the length of returned array or find particular value which is present in `companies` but doesn't exist in returned array.

Additionally since you're using callback style you need to further process your `errors` array within that callback, in your current code the `if (!errors.isEmpty()) {` line gets executed before the database returns any query results. Thus your solution can look like below:

```
companySchema.find({ _id: { $in: companies } }, { _id: 1 }, function (err, queryResult) {
    for(let company of companies){
        if(!queryResult.find(x => x._id === company )){
            errors.push({ message: "COMPANY_NOT_EXIST_ERROR"});
        }
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {        
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(temp_folder + req.files[i].filename);
            } catch(err) {
                errors.push({ message: "DELETE_FILE_ERROR"});
            }
        }
        return res.status(422).json({
            message: errors.message
        })
    }
    else { console.log("success!")};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that mickl. A couple follow-up questions: 1) my "errors" variable is not defined within the .find since it's instantiated outside of the .find. Should I move all my logic around checking the validators, etc.into the .find as well? 2) I oversimplified my code. I need to check both companies and whether a list of employees exist at the companies (also in a separate db collection). For the async reasons mentioned above, should I tackle this with nested .find loops?

Comment: 1) you don't need to move the variable definition but you need to keep in mind that the output of the database query is only visible within the callback 2) it seems like you need to run another asynchronous query to the database so it needs to happen within the callback and you'll have more nested callback. It's better to use `$in` to avoid calling the database in a loop which is inefficient. Also consider using `await` in your solution if possible - it will make your code way more readable.